# Check post attributes during PHP File upload

Tags: php

Hi I have the following saved as upload.php.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        for($file_count = 0; $file_count <= count($_FILES['files']['tmp_name']); $file_count++){
            echo '111111';
            if( $_FILES['files']['error'][$file_count] == 0){
                echo '2222222222';
                $target_dir = "uploads/".time().$_FILES['files']['name'][$file_count];
                echo '333333333333';
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$file_count], $target_dir);
                echo '4444444444444';
            }
        }
    ?>
    <div>
        <form method="post" name="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data"
            action="">
            <input type="file" name="files[]" enctype="form/multipart"> <input
                type="submit" id="photo_upload" value="Upload Photo...">
        </form>
        <div id="contents">fggfgfg</div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The upload works fine.
The problem is when I launch the page, I see error messages. (Can't upload screenshots to show them).

To avoid them I tried checking if the form was set in the post request like so:
if(isset($_POST[])).

But when I have the above if block, the code inside it does'nt get executed even when I select and submit the files.

How can I get around this.

QUESTION 2:

Can somebody please point me to jquery based file upload example? I have to asynchrously upload files since there are other form field available on the page.

Comment: You dont have to upload a screenshot to show errors. You can copy and paste the errors/warnings that you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give name attribute to your submit element change it to this

```
<input type="submit" id="photo_upload" name="Submit" value="Upload Photo...">
```

and then check like this

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
```

Comment: if they are notice just forget them or set error_reporting(0)

Comment: Its giving me this error now:
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in upload.php on line 9
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in upload.php on line 11
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in upload.php on line 13

Comment: oh yes they are notice.. thanks it seems to have worked...

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1:
you can check for post variable as well as with file object like

```
if(isset($_FILES))
```

or for using POST you have to assign name tag to your submit button

like

```
<input type="submit" id="photo_upload" name="Submit" value="Upload Photo...">
```

Answer 2 : for file upload with asynchrously you can use jquery file up loader you can check below [live demo](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)

it is very easy to use and customize as we need.